# Spring boot auto updates dependency version

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, gradle

I want a spring boot dependency of elastic-search-rest-client:7.1.0 but since my springboot version is 2.6.7 it is updating to 7.15.2.How do i prevent this from happening

Comment: But you should definitely upgrade the client and the server to 7.17.12

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the managed version by setting the extra property `elasticsearch.version`. You can do so in your `build.gradle` with e.g.

```
ext['elasticsearch.version'] = '7.1.0'
```

or

```
ext {
    set('elasticsearch.version', '7.1.0')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dependency management to directly specify the versions of artifacts to be used when they are encountered in transitive dependencies.
If you are using maven you can do the following

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- specify your elastic-search-rest-client:7.1.0 dependecy" -->
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

This will now only override the transitive version you are getting from spring boot dependency. you can do similary in gradle also using dependency management plugin

```
plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version <<version>>
}
```